# django localisation with one language

Tags: django

I would like to use localisation in my application in the future. So I would like to have my code prepared.

But I have the problem, if user come from language other than CS(main one). In this time, i would like to have all people across the world see just only CS version.

I already set my LANGUAGE_CODE = 'cs'. But when i come with the EN browser, i do not see my main language.

Can you help me?

Thanks,
Tomas

Answer (score 0):

What do you see instead of your main language when using a browser set to EN?

Have you tried setting LANGUAGE_CODE to 'cs-CZ'?